# Issue comparing pandas dates with Python dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is a python code that I wrote but  cannot find where I am doing wrong.I hope someone can help me here in debugging this code
Code:

```
tx_data['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(tx_data['InvoiceDate'])
tx_uk = tx_data.query("Country=='United Kingdom'").reset_index(drop=True)

#create 3month and 6month dataframes
tx_3m = tx_uk[(tx_uk.InvoiceDate < date(2011,6,1)) & (tx_uk.InvoiceDate >= date(2011,3,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
tx_6m = tx_uk[(tx_uk.InvoiceDate >= date(2011,6,1)) & (tx_uk.InvoiceDate < date(2011,12,1))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Issue:

```
32 else:
33 typ = type(right).name
---> 34 raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
35 return res_values

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `datetime` types and Numpy datetimes (used by pandas) are not the same. So you need to convert your `datetime.datetime` in a `numpy.datetime64` to fix the issue.

```
tx_3m = tx_uk[(tx_uk.InvoiceDate < numpy.datetime64("2011-6-1")) & (tx_uk.InvoiceDate >= numpy.datetime64("2011-3-1"))].reset_index(drop=True)
tx_6m = tx_uk[(tx_uk.InvoiceDate >= numpy.datetime64("2011-6-1")) & (tx_uk.InvoiceDate < numpy.datetime64("2011-12-1"))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tx_data['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(tx_data['InvoiceDate']).dt.date
```

Comment: Thank you @meysam. The error is now removed with your suggestion.